# X2Go error: home directory path contains non-ASCII characters

Tags: linux, ascii, x2go

The following error has started appearing for myself and all local users of X2Go when attempting to access a remote Ubuntu workstation:

```
Connection failed. Your home directory path contains non-ASCII characters. Aborting session startup.
```

Connecting via terminal / ssh still works fine. What is likely causing this error and how could I fix it?

Comment: What's the path?

Comment: My home directory contains no such characters. It is just /home/myusername .

Answer (score 4):

The answer is that X2Go will report this error if the root filesystem is full.

Comment: The same error just occurred here. I was able to SSH into the remote server and effectively realized that the disk was full. After deleting a few files I was again able to connect using X2Go.

Answer (score 0):

try this command

```
iconv -f 'ASCII' -t 'ASCII'  <<< "${HOME}
```

This can happen if your iconv doesn't work.

```
iconv: relocation error: iconv: symbol __gconv_open version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference
```

I fixed it by reinstalling libc6 on Ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install libc6
```